# ask about add_rewrite_endpoint query_vars

Tags: php

how to change links
from **sample-domain. com/title-post/download** to **sample-domain. com/download/title-post**

im use this code

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'download', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
function download_links() {
   add_rewrite_endpoint( 'download', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'download_links' );

function download_templates() {
    global $wp_query;
    // if this is not a request for play or a singular object then bail
    if ( ! isset( $wp_query->query_vars['download'] ) || ! is_singular() )
        return;
    // include custom template
    include get_template_directory().'/template/download.php';
    exit;
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'download_templates' );
```

if use this link < ? php the_permalink() ? >download/ working fine

but i want changes **sample-domain. com/title-post/download** to **sample-domain. com/download/title-post**

im using wordpress

please help me to fix my issue. thanks

#wordpress